# Twitter api - get replies in real time

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, webhooks

Is it possible to get user posts and replies to this posts in real time though the Twitter API? I tried to do it with webhooks.

Comment: Perhaps websockets could help you.

Comment: Can you tell more detail about it ?

Comment: Spelling and capitalization.